# What are the shortcomings of javascript's revealing module pattern when unit testing with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

What are the shortcomings of javascript's revealing module pattern when unit testing with Jasmine?

And what are the potential workarounds?

Comment: what is the "revealing module pattern"?

Comment: It's bascially the module pattern. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/02/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern.aspx

Comment: So looks like spy-ability is the main drawback, + testing private methods. I don't consider either of these to be a huge drawback. But none the less, still would be nice to have the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using requireJS, which is a special kind of the module pattern, for over year now and cant see any shortcomings. Your module should use dependency injection so you can replace the dependencies of the module with mocks in your test.

```
var myModule = (function(dep1){
  function someFancyAlgorythm(a){return a +1}
  return {
    foo: function(a){
      dep1(someFancyAlgorythm(a))
    }
  }
})(dep1)
```

in your test

```
describe('myModule',function(){

  var dep1;
  var module;

  beforeEach(function(){
   dep1 = jasmine.createSpy();
   module = myModule(dep1)
  })

  it('make crazy stuff', function(){
    module.foo(1);
    expect(dep1).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  })
})
```

Comment: Running this code (with var dep1 = (function () { return true; }); added) results in [object Object] is not a function (evaluating 'myModule(dep1)') - have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Could try this way

```
var module = (function() {

    var priv = function(){

    };
    var pub = function(){

    };

    /**start-private-test**/
    pub._priv = priv ;
    /**end-private-test**/

    return {
        pub : pub
    }
}();
```

write test for `pub._priv` and production remove code unit `private-test` . for more information read this [blog post](http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the main caveat when you want to unit test a module (regardless of the test runner that is used) is the scope of the inner functions. That is, the inner methods; or if you will the private methods; are not accessible from outside of the module. Hence, it is not very obvious how to unit test those methods; This, of course, applies only in the case that you want to unit test your private methods.

I have written a blog post where this issue is described and a solution is proposed.

http://tech.pro/blog/1792/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-the-revealing-module-pattern

Comment: Thanks kleopatra for the remark. I'll be aware of that from now on.